# URL query syntax for Android Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to use Retrofit to get data from the Overpass API for OpenStreetMap.

The URL String for a GET request looks like this:

```
http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?way[highway=track][bbox=-122.53,37.86,-122.52,37.87]
```

As far as I can tell, the `RestAdapter` would look something like this:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("http://www.overpass-api.de")
    .build();
```

and GET method in the interface would look something like this:

```
@GET("/api/xapi")
Response listWays(WHAT GOES HERE??);
```

The existence of "way" without an accompanying `=someValue` and the `[highway=track]` and `[bbox=...]` in brackets both seem a bit out of the ordinary.

How should I write this interface method for this GET request?

Comment: Retofit can't cover this use case (without ugly gross hacks). Sorry! Can you file an issue: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/new

Comment: @JakeWharton https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/556

Comment: @JakeWharton can't we use something like that
    `@GET("/api/xapi?way[highway={track}][bbox={x1},{x2},{y1},{y2}]")
    Response listWays(String track, double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2);`
?

Comment: @colriot No. I commented on the issue with a proposal.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation you should use @Query parameter of retrofit.